# WeakHashMap with weakly referenced values instead of keys

Tags: java

Is there a Map class in which all the values are weak references? Like WeakHashMap but for values instead of keys.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Wouldn't that just be a `Map<K,WeakReference<V>>`?

Comment: @user2864740: That won't automatically clean up entries for garbage-collected values.

Comment: There is `com.sun.beans.WeakCache,` which has both weak keys and weak values, but you shouldn't use it.

Comment: @user2357112 That's right I need automatic cleanup, like WeakHashMap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [MapMaker](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html) which is part of Guava.

> "Java DOC:A ConcurrentMap builder, providing any combination of these features:
>   soft or weak keys, soft or weak values, timed expiration, and
>   on-demand computation of values."

```
ConcurrentMap<Key, Graph> graphs = new MapMaker()
       .concurrencyLevel(32)
       .softKeys()
       .weakValues()
       .expiration(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
       .makeComputingMap(
           new Function<Key, Graph>() {
             public Graph apply(Key key) {
               return createExpensiveGraph(key);
             }
           });
```

It is pretty much configurable.